# Require model field in admin site only if another model field is true

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, foreign-keys

In one of my models, I want a foreign key object to be required only if another boolean model field is true. How do I configure the admin site to behave this way?

My models.py contains:

```
from django.db import models

class ThingOne(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class ThingTwo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    use_thingone = models.BooleanField()
    thingone = models.ForeignKey(ThingOne, blank=True, null=True)
```

And my admin.py contains:

```
from myapp.models import ThingOne
from myapp.models import ThingTwo
from django.contrib import admin

admin.site.register(ThingOne)
admin.site.register(ThingTwo)
```

How do I adjust this to make `thingone` a required foreign key field only if `use_thingone` is true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You actually only need to override your model's `clean` method:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.db import models

class ThingTwo(models.Model):
    #Your stuff

    def clean(self):
        """
        Validate custom constraints
        """
        if self.use_thingone and self.thingone is None:
            raise ValidationError(_(u"Thing One is to be used, but it not set!"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Create form for the ThingTwo and check what you need in model's clean() method.

Here are creating form for model - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform and using custom form for model admin - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-custom-validation-to-the-admin